# where can I find php_mssql.dll?

Tags: sql-server, php5, windows-7

I'm trying to get PHP set up to connect to a SQL Server database. I'm looking for the php_mssql.dll file to put in my extensions directory but for the life of me can't locate it online. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Download the Zip (not installer) version of your version of PHP from the [PHP site](http://windows.php.net/download/) and extract it, you will find it in the ext folder here.

You can also try the [Microsoft SQL driver for PHP](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/PHP-Driver.aspx)

Comment: Yeah tried that but it aint there. I'm using the VC6 x86 Thread Safe version. There are a lot of dll's in there like mysql, ect but not msssql

Answer (score 1):

You should find it in the "ext" directory of php package, but only of [PHP 5.2.X](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.2.14-Win32-VC6-x86.zip), PHP 5.3 doesn't include dll for mssql.

Comment: It's not there. It is if i was to use PHP 5.2 but not in 5.3. will i have to downgrade?

Comment: For 5.3 (V6) you can try with sysbase extension.

Comment: I uncommented the loadfile line in php.ini for the sybase module but after restarting apache and trying a connection i get call to undefined function. is there anything else i need to add?

Comment: Check with phpinfo() if sysbase module is active. Are you using Apache or IIS?

Comment: Other options: pdo, odbc.